# Did anyone ever put the lid back on Dumbledore's grave?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, deathly-hallows

in the Deathly Hallows Voldemort opens his grave and takes the Elder wand and fires a beam into the sky then uses it to destroy hogwarts etc.

my question is: Did anyone ever put the lid back on or is Dumbledore's grave remained open?

Comment: I find it somewhat unlikely that they left him there for the crows

Comment: left him to rot

Comment: @Himarm - We know that Hogwarts has a [crow problem](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Crow)

Comment: @Richard his body is all over the place now, poor bastard.

Comment: *Accio bits of Dumbledore!*, said Crabbe. *"This has to be the worst detention ever"*, said Goyle.

Comment: Harry declares his intention to put the Elder Wand back into the grave. If it is still open at that point, he’ll certainly close it.

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly valid question. I don't understand why people downvote it. And @chirlu, yours can be counted as an answer. If you could post an answer with sources and quotes from the book, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @apollo: That would be almost exactly what Richard already has written. The exact quote from _Deathly Hallows_ (last regular chapter, _The flaw in the plan_) isn’t particularly interesting, either: *‘I’m putting the Elder Wand’, he [= Harry] told Dumbledore …, ‘back where it came from. It can stay there.’*

Comment: @chirlu You're right, didn't read the answer.

Comment: Just like that Voldemort; never remembers to put the lid down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**We don't know, but probably yes.** At the end of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Harry's plan is to return the wand to Dumbledore's tomb. I think we can reasonably assume that if it hasn't already been repaired, one of Harry's next acts would have been to fix it.

It also seems vanishingly unlikely that the wizards remaining at the castle would have left Dumbledore's corpse exposed to the elements.

Comment: or, seeing as how secretive Voldemort is (he told Snape to leave him alone for a while if I remember the scene correctly) it's likely he closed it himself after he got what he wanted

Answer (score 4):

**It's never actually stated, but it can be safely presumed.**

There are far too many chances for someone to have closed it to think that Dumbledore's grave was left open. Lord Voldemort may have covered the grave back himself, not out of respect, but to keep anyone from realizing it had been tampered with.

Even if he didn't, if another wizard noticed it was open, they might have closed it themselves. Dumbledore was respected and beloved by many, and being wizards, if someone wanted to close it, it wouldn't have taken them much time or physical effort to cover it.

The most conclusive evidence that Dumbledore's grave would have been closed is that Harry planned to put the Elder Wand back in it. Dumbledore was his mentor, who he would later name his son after. Harry clearly cared about him. It would be odd to think Harry would dig Dobby (who was much less important to him than Dumbledore) a grave without using magic, and want to put the Elder Wand with Dumbledore, but would be fine with leaving Dumbledore's grave uncovered.

*(After I finished this I realized a lot of this was already said in the previous answer and comments, but I've typed this up already, so here it is.)*